# How to replace non integer values in a pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe consisting of two columns, Age and Salary

```
Age   Salary
21    25000
22    30000
22    Fresher
23    2,50,000
24    25 LPA
35    400000
45    10,00,000
```

How to handle outliers in Salary column and replace them with an integer?

Comment: `df['col']=df['col'].str.replace("[^0-9]",'')`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If need replace non numeric values use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'`:

```
df['new'] = pd.to_numeric(df.Salary.astype(str).str.replace(',',''), errors='coerce')
              .fillna(0)
              .astype(int)
print (df)
   Age     Salary      new
0   21      25000    25000
1   22      30000    30000
2   22    Fresher        0
3   23   2,50,000   250000
4   24     25 LPA        0
5   35     400000   400000
6   45  10,00,000  1000000
```

Comment: It replace non numeric to NaN.

Comment: and then [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) replace `NaN` to some int, e.g. `0`

Comment: There are three options for `errors`: `raise` is the default and throws an error when it encounters nonnumeric characters. `coerce` returns `NaN` when it encounters nonnumeric characters. `ignore` returns the original value when it can't convert to numeric.

Comment: @latish - please check last edit, need cast values to `str`, because mixed content - `int` with `str` values

Comment: @jezrael what would this look like for multiple columns?

Answer (score 3):

Use numpy where to find non digit value, replace with '0'.

```
df['New']=df.Salary.apply(lambda x: np.where(x.isdigit(),x,'0'))
```

Comment: What if you want to use this to replace part of a value, say it was 25x and you want it to be 250?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Python 3 use the following. I am not sure how other Python versions return type(x). However I would not replace missing or inconsistent values with 0, it is better to replace them with None. But let's say you want to replace string values (outliers or inconsistent values) with 0 :

```
df['Salary']=df['Salary'].apply(lambda x: 0 if str(type(x))=="<class 'str'>" else x)
```